# How to specify process duration - flowable

Tags: java, spring-boot, bpmn, flowable

How can I specify process duration with Flowable? If from startEvent elapse e.g. 30 days and process will not be finished it should be closed. I use Spring Boot with flowable. It should be specified in diagram or in code?

Answer (score 1):

In order to model something like that you can put everything in a sub process and add a boundary timer on that sub process. That timer can have `PT30D` as a definition.

You can read more about this in the [Timer Boundary Events](https://www.flowable.org/docs/userguide/index.html#bpmnTimerBoundaryEvent) section of the Flowable documentation.